# Handling exceptions in stored procedures called using insert-exec blocks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that is called in an insert-exec block:

```
insert into @t
    exec('test')
```

How can I handle exceptions generated in the stored procedure and still continue processing?

The following code illustrates the problem.  What I want to do is return 0 or -1 depending on the success or failure of the internal `exec()` call:

```
alter procedure test -- or create
as
begin try
    declare @retval int;
    -- This code assumes that PrintMax exists already so this generates an error
    exec('create procedure PrintMax as begin print ''hello world'' end;')
    set @retval = 0;
    select @retval;
    return(@retval);
end try
begin catch
    -- if @@TRANCOUNT > 0 commit;
    print ERROR_MESSAGE();
    set @retval = -1;
    select @retval;
    return(@retval);
end catch;
go

declare @t table (i int);

insert into @t
    exec('test');

select *
from @t;
```

My problem is the `return(-1)`.  The success path is fine.

If I leave out the try/catch block in the stored procedure, then the error is raised and the insert fails.  However, what I want to do is to handle the error and return a nice value.

The code as is returns the message:

```
Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
```

This is perhaps the *worst* error message I've encountered.  It seems to really mean "You did not handle an error in a nested transaction."

If I put in the `if @@TRANCOUNT > 0`, then I get the message:

```
Msg 3916, Level 16, State 0, Procedure gordontest, Line 7
Cannot use the COMMIT statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement unless BEGIN TRANSACTION is used first.
```

I've tried playing around with begin/commit transaction statements, but nothing seems to work.

So, how can I have my stored procedure handle errors without aborting the overall transaction?

Edit in response to Martin:

The actual calling code is:

```
        declare @RetvalTable table (retval int);

        set @retval = -1;

        insert into @RetvalTable
            exec('
```

declare @retval int;
exec @retval = '+@query+';
select @retval'
                    );

```
        select @retval = retval from @RetvalTable;
```

Where `@query` is the stored procedure call.  The goal is to get the return value from the stored procedure.  If this is possible without an `insert` (or, more specifically, without starting a transaction), that would be great.

I cannot modify the stored procedures in general to store the value in a table, because there are too many of them.  *One* of them is failing, and I can modify that.  My current best solution is something like:

```
if (@StoredProcedure = 'sp_rep__post') -- causing me a problem
begin
    exec @retval = sp_rep__post;
end;
else
begin
    -- the code I'm using now
end;
```

Comment: What are you trying to insert into the table variable? The return value doesn't get inserted there anyway. 
`declare @t table (i int);declare @RC int;exec @RC = test;insert into @t values (@RC);select * from @t;` works fine.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . The way the code really works is more like  `select @retval; return @retval` at the end.  If you know another way to get the return value from a dynamic stored procedure call, I would love to know.

Comment: Well another way would be `DECLARE @RC INT;EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC @RC = test', N'@RC INT OUTPUT', @RC = @RC OUTPUT;insert into @t VALUES (@RC)`

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . I think that will work.  We spent half the day looking for hardware fault ("cannot support operations that write to the log file" sounds like a hardware failure) and the past couple of hours trying to get the code right.  Variable substitution is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error in the `EXEC` part of the `INSERT-EXEC` statement is leaving your transaction in a doomed state.

If you `PRINT` out [`XACT_STATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx) in the `CATCH` block it is set to `-1`.

Not all errors will set the state to this. The following check constraint error goes through to the catch block and the `INSERT` succeeds.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE test -- or create
AS
  BEGIN try
      DECLARE @retval INT;

      DECLARE @t TABLE(x INT CHECK (x = 0))

      INSERT INTO @t
      VALUES      (1)

      SET @retval = 0;

      SELECT @retval;

      RETURN( @retval );
  END try

  BEGIN catch
      PRINT XACT_STATE()

      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();

      SET @retval = -1;

      SELECT @retval;

      RETURN( @retval );
  END catch;
```

Adding this to the `CATCH` block

```
 IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END;
```

Doesn't help. It gives the error

> Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement.

I don't think there is any way of recovering from such an error once it has happened. For your specific use case you don't need `INSERT ... EXEC` anyway though. You can assign the return value to a scalar variable then insert that in a separate statement.

```
DECLARE @RC INT;

EXEC sp_executesql
  N'EXEC @RC = test',
  N'@RC INT OUTPUT',
  @RC = @RC OUTPUT;

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES      (@RC)
```

Or of course you could restructure the called stored procedure so that it doesn't raise that error at all.

```
DECLARE @RetVal INT = -1

IF OBJECT_ID('PrintMax', 'P') IS NULL
  BEGIN
      EXEC('create procedure PrintMax as begin print ''hello world'' end;')

      SET @RetVal = 0
  END

SELECT @RetVal;

RETURN( @RetVal );
```