# Handling exceptions with INSERT-EXEC with linked server stored proc and table results

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I am trying to capture failures for a remote (via linked server) stored procedure called within a local stored procedure. If the remote procedure fails (error connecting to server, etc) I want the return value or an indicator for this so I can capture this and log it. If it doesn't fail, I want the results which would be used within the local procedure and processed as a temp table.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE(id INT,
        TransDAte date,
        Description nvarchar(25))


INSERT INTO @myTable

select * from openquery(MyLinkedServer, 'EXEC   [MyDatabase].[dbo].[RemoteStoredProc]')
```

The below link is on the right track but I have two differences. One, my table is multiple fields that I need to return (In the example, @RC is a list of INTs) and I am just selecting the data to use in the local stored procedure, I do not need to commit or rollback transactions.

[Handling exceptions in stored procedures called using insert-exec blocks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34275/handling-exceptions-in-stored-procedures-called-using-insert-exec-blocks)

I have tried adding catch/try statements to both the local and remote procedures but they don't capture the failures correctly.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
Create PROCEDURE thisTEST
AS

DECLARE @myTable TABLE(tableid INT,
        TransDAte date,
        Description nvarchar(25))

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO @myTable
     select * from openquery(MyLinkedServer, 'EXEC  [MyDatabase].[dbo].[RemoteStoredProc]')
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    print 'Create entry in error log table'
END CATCH
```

-- This doesn't work because the remote procedure failure is not captured. When the procedure fails, the sproc attempts to insert the error message into the tableid field)

```
Create procedure RemoteStoredProc
AS

BEGIN TRY


Select transactionid, transactiondate, myDescription from SourceTable


END TRY


BEGIN CATCH
print 'Error with getting data'

END CATCH
```

---

I tried adding an output parameter but I don't know how to execute an Insert-Exec procedure with output and/or results

```
Create procedure RemoteStoredProcWParam(@sprocFailed INT OUT)

AS


BEGIN TRY


Select transactionid, transactiondate, myDescription from SourceTable

SET @sprocFailed = 0

END TRY


BEGIN CATCH
Set @sprocFailed = 1
print 'Error with getting data'

END CATCH
```

It looks like the best option is an output parameter with a cursor to store table results but I don't think that will work either.  I am used to using SSIS but don't want to have to rewrite two entire (complicated) stored procedures. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance